# Extracting file with ZipInputStream error UTFDataFormatException

Tags: android, zipinputstream

I have an error while I try to extract the files of a .zip that I have stored in my assets folder, the error appear because my file have the character ñ. The error throws when I try to get next entry: `zipIs.getNextEntry()`

```
private void loadzip(String folder, InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
{
            ZipInputStream zipIs = new ZipInputStream(inputStream); 
            ZipEntry ze = null;

            int i=0;
                while ((ze = zipIs.getNextEntry()) != null) {

                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(folder +"/"+ ze.getName());

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length = 0;

                    while ((length = zipIs.read(buffer))>0) {
                    fout.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }


                    zipIs.closeEntry();
                    fout.close();


                }
                zipIs.close();
}
```

## **SOLUTION**

Using [zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/)

```
private void loadZip(String zipFileName, String destination)
        {
            ZipFile zipFile = null;
            List<FileHeader> headers = null;
            try {
                zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFileName);
                headers = zipFile.getFileHeaders();

            } catch (ZipException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(headers != null)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<headers.size();i++)
                {
                    try {
                        zipFile.extractFile(headers.get(i),destination);

                    } catch (ZipException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

.................................................................................................................................

If you want to load from assets (my case), you have to move your zip to sdcard folder and after that extract it:

```
private ArrayList<String> moveZipsFromAssets(String[] zipsAssets, String destination)
        {
            ArrayList<String> zips = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=0;i<zipsAssets.length;i++)
            {
                InputStream inputStream = getInputStream(zipsAssets[i]);
                Log.d(tag, ""+zipsAssets[i]);
                File file = new File(destination+"/"+zipsAssets[i]);
                try {
                        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                        int read = 0;
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                        }

                        outputStream.close();
                        zips.add(destination+"/"+zipsAssets[i]);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return zips;
        }
```

example use (we have a folder assets/myZipsFolder/ where are all the zips):    `ArrayList

```
zipsExternos = moveZipsFromAssets(getAssets().list("myZipsFolder"),
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myZipsFolder");

//and load the zips:
for(int i=0;i<zipsExternos.size();i++)
   loadZip(zipsExternos.get(i),Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myZipsFolder");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a third-party library such as [zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/). Their ZipInputStream implementation supports non-UTF8 file names.

*Edited because `ZipInputStream(InputStream, Charset)`is not available in Android.*

Comment: `ZipInputStream(inputStream, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));` doesnt exist, debugger says that I have to remove Charset to match with `new ZipInputStream(InputStream);`

Comment: You are right this constructor is JDK 1.7 only and not available in Android. I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks it solves my prolem I will put the entire code