# ZipInputStream(BufferedInputStream, Charset) is undefined

Tags: java, android, zipinputstream

I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509264/extracting-file-with-zipinputstream-error-utfdataformatexception) question and I saw that exist a constructor of ZipInputStream called:

`ZipInputStream(BufferedInputStream, Charset)`

but the debugger throws me the error:

`ZipInputStream(BufferedInputStream, Charset) is undefined`

and give me the advice:

`remove the argument to match ZipInputStream(InputStream)`

I have installed the latest [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and JRE 7 but I still have the same error.

**Finally I solved the problem here:**

[Extracting file with ZipInputStream error UTFDataFormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509264/extracting-file-with-zipinputstream-error-utfdataformatexception)

Comment: Looks like you hove imported different classes. Make sure that you have imported `java.nio.charset.Charset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you programm an android app you're using the android libraries. The [android `ZipInputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) has no public constructor with signature `ZipInputStream(InputStream, Charset)`. It doesn't matter what JDK or JRE you install on your PC, since you're app will not run on the PC (or  on the PC but in an emulator).

Comment: And there is an alternative? I have files in my zip with special characters.

Comment: @ƒernandoValle: I don't have much experience with java / android and charsets but it looks like [InputStreamReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) with the ZipInputStream as constructor parameter could do the trick.

Comment: @fabian - I doubt it.  The Charset is specifying the encoding for ZipEntry names, not the files themselves.

Comment: I solved finally here using an external library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509264/extracting-file-with-zipinputstream-error-utfdataformatexception

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is no alternative in the Android API.  However, if you can arrange that the ZIP file has the "Language encoding flag (EFS)" bit set, then a recent version of android should respect it, and thread the entry names as UTF-8 encoded.

Note that the 2nd `ZipInputStream` constructor was added to the (real) Java class libraries in Java 7, and the Android APIs are based on Java 6.

Reference:

- [Issue 4690: ZipFile.java corrupts UTF-8 encoded ZipEntry.name](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4690)

Comment: How I set the EFS flag to a zip file using for example 7zip or other compressor? I have search about it but I didn't find a lot.

Comment: thanks finally I solve my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509264/extracting-file-with-zipinputstream-error-utfdataformatexception